# How to manually use estimatedSize from FlowLayout

Tags: ios8, uicollectionview, size, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

In iOS 8 we got a opportunity to create autosize cells with property flowlayout called estimated Size.
But in my case i want use this opportunity manually.
but can't understand how?
In method of delegate sizeForItemAtIndexPath i can't call dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier, because i get error

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

I can't understand, how i can get size of cell in sizeForItemAtIndexPath before cellForItemAtIndexPath?

How it's doing collectionViewFlowLayout?

Also in iOS 8 we got systemLayoutSizeFittingSize but it's also works on already created cells.

Answer (score 0):

I found maybe a solution

```
+ (CGSize)sizeForViewFromNib:(NSString *)nibName width:(CGFloat)width userData:(id)userData {
        UIView *view = viewFromNib(nibName, nil);
    [view configForUserData:userData];
    CGSize size = [view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:CGSizeMake(width, SOME_MIN_SIZE) withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel];
    return CGSizeMake(width, size.height);
}
```

Point here it's
**UIView *view = viewFromNib(nibName, nil);**